# How can we keep track of changes in config maps?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Sometimes recent changes done in config maps are needed , how can we retrieve this history?
Is there any utility provided by k8s to keep track of these changes?
If not , How can we achieve it?

My env is made up of OCP,K8S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of data are you storing in config maps?There is no utility provided by Kubernetes.You really need to treat config as code and store config maps in your source code version control system like git.

Comment: Yes , we can do this.

Comment: But with OCP we can edit config maps when pods are running.

Comment: When we edit config maps directly by OCP then those changes are not tracked , is there any utility to overcome this?